# Multi tenant windows phone app

Tags: azure, windows-phone

I have a windows azure service which is multi tenant aware (using business_id), but how do I identify the phone client. The app does not have any authentication. Basically what I am looking for is when the app is downloaded from the windows store, a unique identifier is set on the app and when its installed and run the very first time a new azure db with that identifier is created. Then when the user can interact with only his/her database via the service. 
I could not find any article on this topic. Can someone point me in the right direction.